# Configuring apache virtual hosts for one domain and multiple IP addresses

Tags: apache, dns

I have two apache servers at two separate IP addresses and one domain name (example.com) administer on godaddy.com. I want to use this single domain to point traffic to my two separate servers over ssl.

I set up the first server through a fios router with port forwarding and associated the public IP address with a DDNS address (xxx.ddns.net). My godaddy config looks like this:

```
Type    Name    Value   
-------------------------------
A       @       184.168.131.241
CNAME   www     xxx.ddns.net


Forwarding 
------------
domain  https://www.example.com
```

... and my apache ssl.conf file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ...
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine, but now I want to set up a subdomain ('mysub') so that traffic directed to mysub.example.com gets handled by my second server available at a separate IP address (MY.2ND.IP.ADDR). I've tried all sorts of settings on godaddy and in the ssl.conf file, but to no avail. In particular, I've tried:

1. Setting godaddy so that traffic sent to subdomain mysub.example.com is redirected straight to MY.2ND.IP.ADDR; it's not at all clear to me if this is possible. (Godaddy has a form under the title "Forwarding" and a subsection therein called "subdomain", but setting that subdomain to mysub and setting "forward to" to http://MY.2ND.IP.ADDR doesn't seem to do anything; what is this 'subdomain' field in the godaddy interface supposed to be used for?)
2. Directing all traffic to the first server, and configuring apache to proxy traffic for the subdomain on to the second server.

I've tried adding another virtual host element to ssl.conf like so:

```
<VirtualHost MY.2ND.IP.ADDR:443>
    ServerName mysub.example.com
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    <Location />
            ProxyPass http://MY.2ND.IP.ADDR
            ProxyPassReverse http://MY.2ND.IP.ADDR
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

... but this doesn't work either.

In summary, what is the best way to direct traffic for a subdomain to a separate IP address using godaddy and/or apache configurations?

Comment: There is no difference in setting up `www.example.com` or `qqq.example.com` or `anythingelse.example.com`

Comment: @DusanBajic Right, I get that if I were only setting up ONE subdomain with ONE IP Address then the set up would be identical and, as I said, I got the www working no problem. But I am having trouble setting up MULTIPLE subdomains for SEPARATE IP Addresses. So, can I do this purely through godaddy config, or do I need to send all traffic to one of the apache servers and split, so to speak, traffic according to subdomain with virtualhost declarations?

Comment: All you really should need is another DNS entry: `Type: A, Name: mysub, Value: MY.2ND.IP.ADDR`. Of course, on that IP address should be webserver configured to resnond to http(s) requests for Host: mysub.example.com

Comment: @DusanBajic I got there in the end. Your last comment was the breakthrough -- I was indeed forgetting to configure the second server with a "ServerName mysub.example.com" directive. Much appreciated!